# Sort case code blocks on the basis of case labels

Tags: vim

How does one sort code blocks associated with each case (as part of a large switch case construct) on the basis of the case label?

What I want is to transform -

```
switch(val)
{
    case C_LABEL:
        /* do something */
        break;

    case A_LABEL:
        /* do something else*/
        break;

    case B_LABEL:
        /* do something really different */
        break;

    default:
        printf("'val' not recognized");
}
```

into -

```
switch(val)
{
    case A_LABEL:
        /* do something else */
        break;

    case B_LABEL:
        /* do something really different */
        break;

    case C_LABEL:
        /* do something */
        break;

    default:
        printf("'val' not recognized");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Turn each case into a one liner:

   ```
   :fromline,tolineg/case/.,/break/s/\n/§
   ```
2. Sort them:

   ```
   :fromline,tolinesort
   ```
3. Reformat them:

   ```
   :fromline,tolines/§/\r/g
   ```

Notes:

- Visual mode can be a practical way to define the range for those commands.
- You could make a macro if you have to do that often.

Comment: That was beautiful! I couldn't have come up with this even if I spent hours pondering over this problem, primarily because of the fact that a 'pattern match' can be used as a range argument somehow doesn't stick in my mind.

Answer (score 2):

My [AdvancedSorters plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4958) simplifies the steps outlined in @romainl's answer:

```
:/^switch/+2,/default:/-1 SortRangesByHeader /case /
```

The initial range limits the sorting of the lines to the `case` parts. The `:SortRangesByHeader` command from the plugin defines ranges based on the `case` statement, and sorts those.

Comment: The idea seems good but the plugin is throwing errors in my version of Vim.

Comment: Which one? Have you tried the updated version 1.01 (+ ingo-library 1.021)? You can also send me the details via email.

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of outside help:

```
:command! -range SortCases execute "<line1>,<line2>!ruby -e 'puts STDIN.read.split(/(?<=\\n)(?=[\\x20\\x09]*(?:case|default)\\b)/).sort'"
```

then you can do `vi{:SortCases<CR>` to do what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a plugin to do this with the following command:

`:SortBlockBy case`

Check it out
https://github.com/chiedo/vim-sort-blocks-by